# php preg_replace not working like expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got the following code:

```
<?php
    $test = "xxxx..AAA?!";
    echo $test."\n";
    $test = preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "", $test);
    echo $test."\n";
?>
```

I want to delete all chars which aren't letters, numbers or a minus

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

delimiter is missing

```
$test = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', $test); 
echo $test . "\n";
```

Additionally, I recommend using `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\n"` for newline characters.

Comment: note: if you use: `$test = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/', '', $test);` it will be faster because it need to do less operations